# one time registration for app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

**My registration class**

I want my app to have a one time registration process. That is, the first time my app starts I want to launch from a registration page and then onwards from login page

But I'm getting a null pointer exception. Please help me

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Registration extends Activity {

    EditText name;
    EditText pswd;
    EditText confirm;
    EditText guname;
    EditText gpswd;
    ImageView done;
    boolean completed;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);
        completed = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("complete", false);
        if (completed == true) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(Registration.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
        pswd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_pswd);
        confirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_confirmpswd);
        guname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_guname);
        gpswd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_gpswd);
        done = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.reg_done);
        done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefs", 0);
                String namevalue = name.getText().toString();
                String pswdvalue = pswd.getText().toString();
                String confirmvalue = confirm.getText().toString();
                String gunamevalue = guname.getText().toString();
                String gpswdvalue = gpswd.getText().toString();
                if (pswdvalue.equals(confirmvalue) && !namevalue.equals("")
                    && !pswdvalue.equals("") && !confirmvalue.equals("")
                    && !gunamevalue.equals("") && !gpswdvalue.equals("")) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editors = sharedPrefs.edit();
                    editors.putString("spname", name.getText().toString());
                    editors.putString("sppswd", pswd.getText().toString());
                    editors.putString("spguname", guname.getText().toString());
                    editors.putString("spgpswd", gpswd.getText().toString());
                    editors.putBoolean("complete", true);
                    editors.commit();
                    Intent reg_done=new Intent(Registration.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(reg_done);
                } else if (namevalue.equals("") || pswdvalue.equals("")
                    || confirmvalue.equals("") || gunamevalue.equals("")
                    || gpswdvalue.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter all fields",
                        1000).show();
                } else if (!pswdvalue.equals(confirmvalue)
                    && !namevalue.equals("") && !pswdvalue.equals("")
                    && !confirmvalue.equals("") && !gunamevalue.equals("")
                    && !gpswdvalue.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Passwords Mismatch", 1000).show();
                    pswd.setText("");
                    confirm.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
    12-14 23:41:35.044: D/dalvikvm(2065): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 51K, 6% free 2583K/2744K, paused 149ms, total 150ms
12-14 23:41:35.114: I/dalvikvm-heap(2065): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.000MB for 1441932-byte allocation
12-14 23:41:35.254: D/dalvikvm(2065): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 3991K/4156K, paused 139ms, total 139ms
12-14 23:41:37.554: D/AndroidRuntime(2065): Shutting down VM
12-14 23:41:37.554: W/dalvikvm(2065): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2e91648)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo              

            {com.example.test/com.example.test.Registration}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at com.example.test.Registration.onCreate(Registration.java:35)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-14 23:41:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(2065):     ... 11 more
12-14 23:41:44.034: I/Process(2065): Sending signal. PID: 2065 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this on top

```
sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefs", 0);
```

just after

```
setContentView(R.layout.registration);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.....but on back button press in the login page it goes back to the registration page..i need to close the app on back button press

Comment: calling the finish() code didnt work...should i override the back button in login activity

Comment: That means you have called `startActivity()` elsewhere without a `finish()`. However, none of this is related to the question you asked.

Comment: yes i did start the activity in a different place without calling finish..Thanks haike00